# How do I directly add/pin web page to Google Chrome jump list?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, jumplist

Sometimes I want to (easily) add the link for a web page I'm viewing with Google Chrome to Chome's Windows 7 jump list. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried dragging the icon to the immediate left of the URL in the [address bar or omnibox](http://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95440) onto Chrome's jump list, but this doesn't seem to "take".

The only way I have found that works is rather kludgey. If I close the tab for the page I want to add then it shows up in the jump list under "Recently Closed". I can then pin the link to the jump list.

It would be nice to have a way to add a web page to the jump list without first having to close it.

---

### Update (31 March 2012)

To be honest, I really don't remember exactly what I was doing when I asked this question about 1 1/2 years ago other than I was trying to add *pinned* items to the entry for Chrome in my Windows 7 `Start` menu/list.

I just tried dragging the `globe` ... the icon to the immediate left of the URL in the [address bar or `omnibox`](http://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95440) ... to the `Start` menu entry for Chrome and it *still* did not add the link to the jump list.

**However**, dragging & dropping ***does*** work if Chrome is pinned to the Windows *taskbar*, not the `Start` menu.

At any rate, I have marked the question as answered since I have enough of an answer for my purposes. That being, pin Chrome to your taskbar then drag & drop the icon at the immediate left of the link in the Chrome address bar to the Chrome icon pinned to your taskbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you dragged the bookmark star. That is not the correct way to drag a bookmark in Chrome. Instead, drag the *globe icon* to the **left** of the Omnibar.

---

Dragging items to the taskbar to pin them only works for items that have an associated program. For example, create a file name `test.blahbloofoobar` (or something) and drag it to the taskbar. You’ll notice that the cursor changes to the *not allowed/valid* cursor and it doesn’t pin. Now rename the file to `test.txt` and repeat. It should now pin the program associated with text files (defaults to Notepad) to the taskbar and pin that specific file as well.

Try dragging a bookmark to the desktop, then drag it to the taskbar. Try creating a dummy file named `test.url` and drag that to the taskbar. If neither works, then try (re-)setting Chrome as your default browser: `Wrench->Options->Basics->Make…default…` (consider rebooting afterwards).

Comment: +1, dragging the globe is exactly how you pin a URL to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin the website to the jump list on the start menu (I'm assuming that's what you mean)  It has only recently closed and most visited.  Simply close the tab, and then pin it.  Windows will populate a new list called pinned.

[image]

**UPDATE** I just fully read your questions and realize this is alredy what you are doing.  There is another way to customize the jump lists.  [Here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-your-own-custom-jump-list) is how to do it.  I only went briefly over it though, it may not be exactly what you are looking for.